# Regex python until first word

Tags: python, regex

I have a following code:

```
test_string = "Hello Hello World World"
pattern = "Hello World".replace(" ","[\w\W]+")
match = re.search(pattern, test_string)
print(match)
```

The output is `Hello Hello World World` but not `Hello Hello World`

What can I change so that regex stops when it find the 1st World?

Tried several regex expression but still confused

Answer (score 0):

pattern = "Hello World".replace(" ","[\w\W]+?")

Solved the solution. Thanks!